# PHP-Script to check if user is logged in not working as expected

Tags: php, session-variables

**Problem**

I am building a panel for an admin for a web system. I have to make sure that hackers, if they have knowledge of the names of the files on this server cannot access certain pages directly without at least logging in.
Now after looking at similar php code used to achieve this, i discovered that after you have verified the existence of the user from the database, you **start a session** and then you store a `boolean` variable indicating whether this user is logged in side the `$_SESSION["loggedin"]` as `true`.
I did exactly that in my `login.php` file, and also included a conditional structure to check if user is logged in on top of my `admin_upload.php` file. It checks the value of `$_SESSION["loggedin"]`.

**What I Expected**

I expected that whenever i enter the url to access diirectly the `admin_upload.php` file on the server without logging in, it would take me to `login.php` to start a session before i can view that page, instead it opens the page with values that am supposed to grab from login with session null.

**Code**

The **login.php** file is posted below

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","rating");
if(!$conn){
    echo "Connection to database was unsuccesful";
}
$username="";
$password="";
$username=trim($_GET["p"]);
$password=trim($_GET["q"]);
//echo $password;
$sql="SELECT username from Admin where username="."'".$username."'";
//echo $sql;
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    $pass="SELECT Password FROM Admin WHERE username="."'".$username."'";
    $real_qry=mysqli_query($conn,$pass);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($real_qry)>0){
        $row=mysqli_fetch_row($real_qry);
        $pass=$row[0];
        //echo $password;
        if(password_verify($password, $pass)){
          //start session
            session_start();
            //store the admn name in a session 
            $_SESSION["username"]=$username;
            $_SESSION["loggedin"]=true;
            echo "password verification passed";
        

        }else{
            echo "Incorrect password";
        }
    }
}else{
    echo "No account with that username was found";
}
?>
```

The **admin_upload.php** is posted below

```
<?php
session_start();
//initiaize the session
//check if the user is logged in
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
//redirect to welcome.php if false
        header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
//session_start();
$name=$_SESSION["username"];
//if he is loged in then display images to be added
include "layout/product_add.php";

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="materialize/css/materialize.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
</html>
```

Any help to make this check if user is logged in and redirect accordingly is greatly appreciated, Thank You.

Comment: What is the problem with the current script? any error?

Comment: @navnath, yeah when i enter the url of the second file in the address bar, instead of the server checking to see if the user is logged in and redirect to login.php, it opens the page with null session variables, like username for example is empty

Comment: I guess this condotion make your problem: if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true). Because what about when variable is not set?

Comment: @Marty1452, I did not think about that, correcting in a few.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: @Dharman,  I am just querying data from the database not inserting so how am I vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: It doesn't matter what the operation is. SQL injection happens when you concatenate PHP variables with SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your going to want to update

```
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
```

with

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || !$_SESSION["loggedin"]) {
```

That verifies that the `$_SESSION["loggedin"]` is not set OR that its set and NOT TRUE then it will do your redirection